# Convergence of $ (x^n)/n$ for $x \ge 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm a bit confused. I *think* that it's uniformly convergent on [0,1]. My proof: Let $\epsilon$ be greater than 0. Then, $N$ exists in the natural numbers such that $N \,\epsilon > 1$. Then, for all $x \in [0,1]$, $|fn(x) - f(x)| = x^n/n < 1/n < \epsilon$ for all $n \ge N$.

But, for $x \in (1, \infty)$, I'm not sure what to do. It doesn't converge uniformly, I'm pretty sure. I can't negate the definition, since it doesn't even have a pointwise limit. It blows up for n large enough. Is there some sort of Cauchy equivalent that I need?

EDIT: I tried this: pf. Set e0 = 1/2, m=N,n=2N. Then, for all N in the natural numbers, |x^n/n-x^m/m| = |(2Nx^(2N)-Nx^N)/N|= |((Nx^(2N)-2Nx^N)/2N| >= |(Nx^(2N)-2Nx^(2N))/2N| >= |-Nx^(2N))/2N| >= |(-N/2N| = 1/2 = e0.

Does that work? I negated Cauchy and tried to apply it to a sequence of functions.

Comment: If $x > 1$ then we can write $x = 1+a$ where $a > 0$. Now evaluate the first few terms of $(1+a)^n$ using the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument that $f_n \to 0$ uniformly in the interval $[0,1]$ is correct.

I can't understand your argument for $(1,\infty)$. It's not hard to show that $f_n(x) \to \infty$ for every $x \in (1,\infty)$. Here is one approach.

Suppose $x > 1$. Then we can write $x = 1 + a$ for some $a > 0$. The binomial theorem tells us that if $n \geq 2$ we have
$$x^n = (1 + a)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}a^k \geq {n \choose 2}a^2 = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}a^2$$
where the inequality holds because all of the terms in the sum are positive. Dividing both sides by $n$, we conclude that
$$\frac{x^n}{n} \geq \frac{n-1}{2}a^2$$
so $x^n / n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't sure what you meant earlier, since we haven't had to use the binomial theorem. I see it now. For what I did, I thought the negation of Cauchy is that there exists e0>0, m,n in the natural numbers s.t. for all N in the natural numbers |xn-xm|>=e0. I just tried to transcend that to sequence of functions.

Answer (score 0):

As Bungo says,
for $x > 1$
write $x = 1+a$
and just use the
first $3$ terms
of the binomial theorem:

$\frac{x^n}{n}
=\frac{(1+a)^n}{n}
\ge \frac{1+na+n(n-1)a^2/2}{n}
\gt a+(n-1)a^2/2
\gt (x-1)+(n-1)(x-1)^2/2
\to \infty
\text{ as } n \to\infty
$.